# Discuss Existence and uniqueness of solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal S$ be the system defined by :
\begin{cases}
\dot x=5x-3y+2e^{3t}\\ \dot y=x+y+5e^{-t}
\end{cases}
Discuss the existence and uniqueness.

I found that the general solution of $\mathcal S$ is :
$$X(t)=c_1\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{2t}+ c_2\begin{bmatrix}3 \\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{4t}- \begin{bmatrix}4e^{3t}+e^{-t} \\2e^{3t}+2e^{-t} \end{bmatrix}, \quad (c_1,c_2) \in \mathbb R^2.$$
Is that sufficient to say that the solution exists ? I don't have the initial condition to apply Peano theorem ! the same thing with Picard theorem to show uniqueness ! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can rewrite your system as an unique vector-valued linear ODE and then apply the standard theory of linear ODEs.

Comment: What do you know about existence and uniqueness of general linear DE and linear systems of DE? Then there is no need to compute explicit solutions, you can read off the domain from the coefficients of the equation.

Comment: Thank you so much @LutzLehmann, I know Picard and Peano theorems but here there is no initial condition to apply them, so can you please help !

Comment: You need also the statements on the maximal solution, or on situations where the ODE is globally defined in the state direction and globally Lipschitz.

Comment: Thank you  @LutzLehmann, but to be honest i did'nt know what to do ! how can I discuss the existence and uniqueness ? so can you please write down a small answer !

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you for your answer ! I  tried but in vain ! so can you give me a hand ?

Comment: @BRH I do not understand: you have found a family of solutions and the standard theory of ODEs state that there is only one, so you have found ALL the solutions to your system!

Comment: The short of it is that in linear systems of DE over some time interval $I$ where all the coefficient functions are continuous on $I$, every solution has the full interval $I$ as its domain. The same is true for any spacially unrestricted and globally Lipschitz ODE system.